# Oracle SQL Developer Works SQLplus DOESN'T

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, database-administration

With Oracle SQL-Developer I'm able to connect to my VMware CentOS 7 Oracle database ORCL.

if I try to connect with SQLPlus I'm told the realm doesn't exist.

Any idea as to why I can connect with Oracle SQL-Developer and not SQLPlus on the same machine?

TNSPing resolves the SID/Service name without any problems.

```
C:\oracle\ora11g\11.2.0.2\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (Host = 192.168.1.50) (Port = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)))
OK (10 msec)
```

Here's the output from the SQLPlus connection attempt from the same machine that SQL-Developer is working without any issues.

```
C:\oracle\ora11g\11.2.0.2\BIN>sqlplus system/password@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jul 3 08:31:13 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3640
Additional information: -2140813497
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

[image: Updated Results]

Answer (score 1):

Your sqlplus command, try this:

```
 sqlplus user/password@192.168.1.50:1521/ORCL
```

In SQL Developer, once you're connected, run this:

```
show tns
show connection
```

[image]

Make sure you're actually trying to connect to the same database in SQLPlus, also make sure your $ORACLE_HOME and $ORACLE_SID are properly configured.

Comment: see my updates, I tried what you said however I'm still unable to connect.

Comment: is this on the same machine? if so, what is the value of your $ORACLE_HOME ?

Comment: Same machine (windows 10) as Oracle SQL Developer. ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\ora11g\11.2.0.2 and ORACLE_SID = ORCL

Comment: on windows should that not look like C:\...\...\product\11.2.0.2\dbhome_1 ?

Comment: I think something is off with your directory value for $ORACLE_HOME, that why it's failing but sqldev works (jdbc/java don't use it)

Comment: Sadly, this oracle directory path had the dbhome_1 truncated from the directory path.  I know I must be missing something simple, but just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: the oracle_home needs to be correct or you'll get that exact error message

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something is wrong with Oracle_Home or your listener.
Could you please - - LSNRCTL and check the status of the same.
If it is fine, then try to connect to sys:

```
sqlplus /nolog
conn / as sysdba
```